# Admob limitation effects other bidding partners

Tags: java, android, admob, facebook-audience-network

When we have ad serving limit on admob account, it also effects other mediation partners like facebook audience network. However Admob says " limited ad serving applies to AdMob Network only and doesn't affect third-party mediation, house ads, and direct sold campaign." We are not getting impressions from facebook audience network when admob is on limit. What should i do

Comment: Hi @Bur Apps,
Did you find the problem? I have the same issue now.